# Green's identity and gradient estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, harmonic-functions

After the proof of the Green's identity in the book "Han Q., Lin F. - Elliptic partial differential equations - AMS (1997)", they state at page 9:

> We may employ the local version of the Green's identity to
>   get gradient estimates without using mean value property.
>
> Suppose $u \in C(\bar{B_1})$ harmonic in $B_1$. For  any fixed
>   radius $0<r<R<1$ choose a cut-off function $\varphi \in
>  C_{0}^{\infty}(B_R)$ such that $\varphi =1$ in $B_r$ and $0 \leq
>  \varphi \leq 1$.
>
> Apply Green's formula to $u$ and $\varphi \Gamma(a, \cdot)$ in $B_1 \setminus
>  B_{\rho}(a)$ for $a \in B_r$ and $\rho$ small enough. We proceed as in
>   the proof of theorem 1.17 ( which is the proof of Green's identity) and we obtain
>
> \begin{align} u(a)=- \int_{r < |x| < R} u(x) \Delta_x \big(\varphi(x)
>  \Gamma(a,x)\big)dx \quad \quad (\star)  \end{align} for any $a \in B_r(0)$
>
> Hence one may prove $\sup_{B_{1/2}}{Du} \leq C \max_{B_1} {|u|}$

where $\Gamma(a, x)$ is the fundamental solution

I can't understand how to derive that bound!

I think I should take the derivative of $u(a)$ w.r.t $a_i$  and get

\begin{align} | \partial_{a_i} u(a)| \leq \int_{r<|x|<R} |u(x)|\left |\Delta_x\big(\varphi(x) \partial_{a_i} \Gamma(a,x)\big)\right| dx
\end{align}

Now I should take outside the maximum of $|u|$ over the closure of the unitary ball, but I don't know how to treat the Laplacian term in the right way

Comment: It might be helpful if you explicitly stated which of the many Green's identities you're calling "Green's identity."

Comment: @mathworker21 the conclusion is fine. Actually I can't understand why the text takes $B_{\frac{1}{2}}$. Is there a precise region to choose it?

Comment: @VoB I mean, they have to choose some number less than $1$. I don't see why any other number would be preferable. $\frac{1}{2}$ suffices in applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You barely have to treat it. You have already shown $$|\partial_{a_i} u(a)| \le \int_{r < |x| < R} |u(x)| \left| \Delta_x(\varphi(x)\partial_{a_i} \Gamma(a,x))\right|dx,$$ so $$\sup_{a \in B_{1/2}} |\partial_{a_i} u(a)| \le \sup_{a \in B_{1/2}}\int_{r < |x| < R} |u(x)| \left| \Delta_x(\varphi(x)\partial_{a_i} \Gamma(a,x))\right|dx.$$ Let $r=\frac{3}{4}$ and $R = \frac{4}{5}$. $\varphi$ is fixed and so all you need is that $$\sup_{a \in B_{1/2}} \int_{3/4 < |x| < 4/5} |\Delta_x(\varphi(x)\partial a_i \Gamma(a,x))|dx < \infty$$ (then just call it $C$), but the integrand changes continuously in $a$ and $\overline{B_{1/2}}$ is compact, so you're good.

Comment: to pass the limit inside the integral you just used the fact that $\Gamma(a,x)$ is an $L^1$ function, right?

Comment: @VoB When did I take a limit?

Comment: Look at my original answer, at the $\star $ point. Here I have just $u(a)$.

Comment: @VoB I'm saying $a \mapsto \int_{3/4 < |x| < 4/5} |\Delta_x(\varphi(x)\partial a_i \Gamma(a,x))|dx$ is a continuous function from $\overline{B_{1/2}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so it has a finite maximum

Comment: I got, by the theorem I mentioned in the orginal post:
$\begin{align} u(a)=- \int_{r < |x| < R} u(x) \Delta_x \big(\varphi(x)
 \Gamma(a,x)\big)dx \end{align}$

Now I want the bound on $\partial_{a_i} u(a)$, so I need to be sure that I can differentiate under the sign of integral. ( Sorry I wrote "limit" before)

Comment: @VoB Yes, $\Gamma(a,x)$ is a nice enough function that differentiating under the integral is allowed. There is an explicit form for $\Gamma(a,x)$.

Comment: Okay, now everything is clear to me! Thanks :)